# dnn_hidden_units parameter in tensorflow wide and deep model

Tags: tensorflow, dotnetnuke

can someone please elaborate on that parameter?

I saw it in the tutorial and didn't understand the numbers that followed.

e.g: `dnn_hidden_units=[500, 250, 100, 50]`

Thanks,

Naor

Answer (score 2):

You build your deep network with 4 layers of hidden units. First uses 500, second 250, third 100 and fourth 50. If You set it to [10,5] then you have 2 layers - first with 10 and second with 5 nodes. 
All are fully connected.